# Преобразование из int/char в String (java)

Tags: java

String a = 'A' + "2";
Содержимое строки а: А2

String a = '1' + "2";
Содержимое строки а: 12

String a = 'A' + '1' + "2";
Почему в строку записывается 1142?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Потому, что первой выполняется операция сложения двух `char`, а при сложении `char` складываются их коды. `'A' (65) + '1' (49) = 114`. После этого полученное число неявно приводится к строке и конкатенируется со строкой `"2"`.